# Keyerror in Python Dictionary

Tags: python

I am stack in something really simple, but I cannot find the right way. I have a dictionary like this one:

```
mydic= {'a': {'mylist':[..,..,..]}, 'b': {'mylist':[..,..,..]}}
```

I am trying to iterate through `mylist` and create a new subdictionary with the results of a function.

```
for i in mydic:
    for j in mydic[i]['mylist']:
         mydic[i]['thenewkey'][j] = myfunction(j)
```

The find dictionary would be like this:

```
mydic= {'a': {'mylist':[..,..,..], 'thenewkey':{'..':'..', '..':'..'}}, 'b': {'mylist':[..,..,..],'thenewkey':{'..':'..', '..':'..'}}}
```

But when I run the code, I have a key error on `thenewkey`. Any idea?

Comment: Are you certain that the keys in `mylist` are appearing in `thenewkey`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create first `mydic[i]['thenewkey']` before assigning to `mydic[i]['thenewkey'][j]`.

Comment: Damn. I thought it happens automatically in the iteration. That's was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, you have to create the `thenewkey` entry before you can add items to it, i.e. you'd have to add `mydic[i]['thenewkey'] = {}` to your outer loop. You *could* use a [`defaultdict(dict)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make Python automatically insert missing entries, but since you have both `list` and `dict` entries, this does not seem like a good idea.

That said, using a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) makes it a bit shorter and IMHO much more readable:

```
for i in mydic:
    mydic[i]['thenewkey'] = {j: myfunction(j) for j in mydic[i]['mylist']}
```